# ASP.NET routing in production evironment

Tags: iis-7, url-routing, asp.net-routing

I have registered a custom asp.net route in a `RouteTable.Routes`.

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
            "View Service",                    
            "home/services/{*ServiceName}", 
            "~/home/displayservice.aspx"   
        );
```

My application uses ASP.NET 4.0 routing system, and everything works fine on a development machine, when I run the web site from Visual Studio to debug.

When I move the site to IIS7, the routing isn't happening when navigating to

```
http://new.komplus.ua/home/services/viruses/antivirus/
```

or any other path that supposed to be handled by the routing system. As a result, I get 404 error from the server.

I am sure I have copied the global.asax and the `/home/displayservice.aspx` to the web server, and have restarted the web site and app pool since update, but the routing still doesn't take place.

Other, non-routed pages, load fine.

Is there any particular configuration to IIS that has to be done in order for ASP.NET 4 routing to work, in comparison to VS2010 debug environment?

Answer (score 0):

In order for ASP.NET 4.0 routing to work in IIS7 it is requried that the web.config has the webServer element decleared. For examle:

```
<system.webServer>     
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">     
   </modules>     
</system.webServer>
```

It is not a requirement in Visual Studio environment, where routing takes place even without this directive in web.config.